# Issue running Python code in R markdown, using Reticulate package

Tags: r, r-markdown, reticulate

I am having an issue running a Python code, which runs well in Python, in R studio. Specifically, I am using R markdown and ran the following and using the Reticulate package to run Py codes in R studio, as recommended [here](http://%20https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
library(haven)
library(tidytext)
library(reticulate)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
#install.packages("lubridate")
#installed.packages("ggplot2")
#install.packages("reticulate")
#install.packages("tidytext")
##install.packages("haven")
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#install.packages("stringr")
#install.packages("readxl")
```

I then ran a PY file path in an R markdown chunk as follows, w/out any errors:

```
use_python("Users/Documents/Sentiment Analysis/task.py")
```

And then ran the actual Py code in an R markdown chunk as follows:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix,ConfusionMatrixDisplay,classification_report
```

and I keep receiving this error: "Error: unexpected symbol in "import pandas", any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Based on a recommendation below, I ran this in R markdown, which ran perfectly:

```
#import libraries
py_install("pandas")
py_install("seaborn")
py_install("numpy")
py_install("matplotlib.pyplot")
py_install("sklearn.pipeline")
```

But I am still getting an error with when I run this in R markdown:
"Error in pd.read_excel('/Users/Documents/df.xlsx') :
could not find function "pd.read_excel"

```
dataset=pd.read_excel('/Users/Documents/df.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please include (or link to) your markdown page.

Comment: Thanks! I added more details to the post and I used a python chunk and entered it into an R markdown chunk.
On your question about the file path, I used a path to a Python binary file.

Answer (score 1):

‪I suppose that you used a python chunk instead of an r chunk for the python code?

And for use_python: “The path to a Python binary. This can be the path to a Python binary on the system, or the path to a Python binary within an already-existing Python environment.”
It looks like you took a py-File instead. You have to take a Python version. Something like that: “use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")”.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I **highliy** recommend to use an Anaconda Environment in the Background where you can install the versions of python and the packages you need. Then just go in R Studio to Tool -> Global Options -> Python and Select the Environment you want to use. This approach will safe you a lot of headache. Creating environments or installing packages through R Studio lead to too many errors and troubleshooting in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if python is available.
https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_available.html

If not check under your settings which environment rstudio is trying to use. Is it trying use maybe the r-reticulate environment? Do you have all necessary packages (pandas etc.) in this environment? You can also install packages right from rstudio e.g. „py_install("pandas").

I set up Anaconda environments with the packages and versions I need for my projects and then just take the environment I need in my global settings in R Studio. This way always works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, check updated question.